# Change color for hover over navbar-brand img

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to change the color of the navbar-brand images on hover. I can't seem to find a solution on any forums specific to what I'm trying to do! Any help is appreciated.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="img/atslogo8.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="avecNavbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand active mx-auto" href="#" id="home">
            <img src="img/home.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="story.html" id="story"> 
            <img src="img/story.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="buy.html" id="buy"> 
            <img src="img/buy.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="recipes.html" id="recipes"> 
            <img src="img/recipes.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="club.html" id="club"> 
            <img src="img/club.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="spicemap.html" id="spicemap"> 
            <img src="img/map.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="catering.html" id="catering"> 
            <img src="img/catering.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="contact.html" id="contact"> 
            <img src="img/contact.png" height="100" width="100"/> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#avecNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Please add the code here.

Comment: apologies, forgot to space it!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot just change the color of image from css in one line.
I recommend you to use 2 seperate image of different color. 
Initially display:none the image that needs to be shown on hover.
And on hover display:none first image and display:-inline-block on second image

html example

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="redimage1.png" class="first"/><img src="greenimage1.png" class="second"/></a>
```

css example

```
.navbar-brand .second{
display:none;
}

.navbar-brand:hover .first{
display:none;
}


.navbar-brand:hover .second{
display:inline-block;
}
```